# Quantum tunneling in a time dependent potential

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-tunneling, instantons

I wonder if I could use the technique for finding the tunneling rate given by $$ \Gamma=2 \Im[ F]$$ where $F$ is the free energy  in case of time dependent potentials? 
Relevant to the previous question, how can I find the perturbation to an instanton  with a week time dependent potential?

I appreciate your help.